# member variable and member function have the same name

Tags: php

```
class test {
    public $isNew;
    public function isNew(){}
}

$ins = new test();
$ins->isNew
```

Here,how does php parse `$ins->isNew`?

Comment: you need the key word `function` before `isNew(){};`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

PHP is not a functional programming language where functions are also data. So `$ins->isNew` wouldn’t be ambiguous to either refer to the method `isNew` or the attribute `isNew`. `$ins->isNew` is always an attribute and `$ins->isNew()` a method call.

Comment: Hm.. In addition, if there exists:  `$this->isNew = function() { .... };`  then ? `isNew()` fires method of variable-d function?

Comment: @T.Todua No, since fields and methods does not share same namespace, presence of `(` character tells PHP to search for method, which will not be found. You have to read property first and than call function - for example like this `($this->isNew)()` ... first parentheses will read property from class instance and create callable expression, which will be then invoked. Other option is to read `isNew` into temporary variable and then use that variable as function: `$method = $this->isNew; $method();`

Answer (score 6):

`$ins->isNew` is the variable.
`$ins->isNew()` is the function.

Answer (score 4):

See the chapter on [Class Basic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in the PHP manual:

```
$ins->isNew   // class member
$ins->isNew() // class method
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `a`, `b`, `c` for easier differentiation. As you can see, you call each of them in a different way, and that is how PHP knows which one you want. You can rename `c()` to `a()` or `b()`, but you cannot rename `$b` to `$a`, because multiple properties with the same variable names are not allowed.

```
class Class
{
    public $a = true;
    public $b = function () {return true;};
    public function c() {return true;}
}

$class = new Class();

$class->a;
($class->b)();
$class->c();
```

That being said, I wouldn't name methods and properties with the same name, unless the method is the actual getter for the property.

```
class Class
{
    private string $name;

    public function name() {
        // Null coalesce assignment operator is available since PHP 7.4
        $this->name ??= $this->fetchNameFromSender();
        $this->name ??= $this->fetchNameFromDocument();
        $this->name ??= $this->fetchNameFromWhatever();

        return $this->name ?? '[Could not fetch name]';
    }

    ...
}

$class = new Class();
$class->name();
```